# Browser saying that flex-basis: content is "Invalid property value"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given:

```css
.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.layout aside,
.layout main {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.layout aside {
  flex: 0 0 content;
  background-color: red;
}

.layout main {
  flex: 1 1 content;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <aside>
    <p>Line 1</p>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
    <p>Line 3</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/pavgoxf7/1/)

My intentions are:

- aside should be as big as the content it contains and never change its width
- main should take the rest of the horizontal space
- both aside and main should have the same height (the maximum of the two)

but if I run that code and inspect it with Chrome I get the following error on both `flex:` statements:

> Invalid property value

and moreover the green box doesn't expand on the right as it should. My Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Mac OS X 10.11.5.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flex-basis: content` is a valid rule, but it's not supported by all browsers yet.

From the spec:

> [***`content`***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)
>
> Note: This value was not present in the initial release of Flexible
>   Box Layout, and thus some older implementations will not support it.
>   The equivalent effect can be achieved by using `auto` together with a
>   main size (`width` or `height`) of `auto`.

Also see MDN for a brief history of the `content` value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Values

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex: 1 1 auto` instead.

It's the shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`, in that order.